# How do I filter my text so that spaces are taken into account?

Tags: java, android, filter

I am creating a searchbox for my app where the user can type stuff into the box and titles are returned in the `recyclerView` below the searchbox. The titles are in a `php` file on the server- the results are filtered, matching what the user types into the search box.

So for example, one of the titles in my `php` file is:

```
red onions
```

If the user types `red`, the `recyclerView` shows as he types:

```
red cabbage
red mushrooms
red onions
```

This part is working correctly.

But when the user types `red o` nothing shows in the `recyclerView`. Whereas, in fact, `red onions` should be appearing.

I'm sure this is happening because in my app I am breaking the php titles into separate words, so the space `(" ")` between `red` and `onions` is causing a problem.

Any idea how I might resove this?

The reason I am splitting the title into words in the first place is so if the user types the second word, `onions`, `red onions` will show as a result in the `recyclerView`, rather than nothing at all.

Here's my code:

```
      @Override
            public Filter getFilter() {
                return new Filter() {
                    @Override
                    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {

                        //the text entered in the search box
                        String charString = charSequence.toString();

                        //if searchbox is empty, show the whole list
                        if (charString.isEmpty()) {
                            categoryListFiltered = categoryList;
                        } else {
                            List<Category> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

                            for (Category row : categoryList) {

                                //split the php title into separate words
                                String[] title_in_php = row.getName().split(" ");

                                //for every split word
                                for (String split_title : title_in_php) {

//if the search term entered is a whole word in the title
                        if (split_title.toLowerCase().startsWith(charString.toLowerCase())) { 

                                        filteredList.add(row);

                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            categoryListFiltered = filteredList;
                        }

                        FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();

                        filterResults.values = categoryListFiltered;
                        return filterResults;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
                        categoryListFiltered = (ArrayList<Category>) filterResults.values;
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                };
            }
```

Comment: The code splits on `" "` which is not included in the String[].  Try `row.getName().startsWith(charString)`;

Comment: thanks but if I do that then only titles beginning with the search term show in the recycler view. If the user types "onions" nothing shows up.

Comment: Then try `row.getName().contains(charString)`.

Comment: Assuming that "onions red" is equivalent to "red onions" then you'll also have to split the entered charString and compound the search with AND.

Comment: @AndrewS With that, if the search term is in any part of the title, results come up in recyclerView. For example, "ion" returns "onion". Looking for whole words only.

Comment: what if the user types "onion onion"?

Comment: With "onion onion" nothing would show, which is correct, because there is no title with that in the db

Comment: Might be easier if you post more comprehensive test data and expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you entered `red o`, it will first check `red` and it will add `row` to filteredList because charString starts with `red` but checking the `o` wont add the `row` to filteredList because charString doesn't start with `o`

Try this (based on the comments):

```
if (split_title.toLowerCase().startsWith(charString.toLowerCase())) {
    filteredList.add(row);
}
else if (row.getName().contains(charString.toLowerCase()) {
    if (!filteredList.contains(row)) {
        filteredList.add(row);
    }
}
```

`if` for checking the split_title (ex.`red`) - filteredList.add(row);

`else if` will check if the `row` contains the `charString`(whole string- ex. `red o`) - filteredList.add(row);

`if (!filteredList.contains(row))` is just to check if the row is already on the list. If not then add it. (To avoid duplication)

Another way is to split charString:

```
String[] charString= charSequence.toString().split(" ")
```

and iterate it:

```
for (int i=0; i<charString.length; i++) {
    for (int n=0; n<title_in_php.length; n++) {
        if (split_title.toLowerCase().startsWith(charString.toLowerCase()) || charString[i].toLowerCase() == title_in_php[n].toLowerCase() || row.getName().contains(charString.toLowerCase()) {
            if (!filteredList.contains(row)) {
                filteredList.add(row);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

so it will check if `charString` starts with `title_in_php` **OR** if `charString` = `title_in_php` **OR** if `row` contains `charString` checking the list of `title_in_php` per `charString`

*[red]* starts with *[red/onion]* **OR** *[red]* = *[red/onion]* **OR** *[red onion]* contains *[red o]*

Comment: Excellent, nice work. I made some slight modifications which I will add to your answer above shortly but in all it solved the problem, tx.